# Django, Security and Settings

Tags: python, django, security, encryption

From [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases), we add all database info as text:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
 }
```

Is it a secure way? Is there any way to save this data as Encrypted data?

Answer (score 45):

It isn't secure, anyone with access to your source control now has access to your database.

The two main methods of storing sensitive data are either with environment variables or via a json file

---

> Excerpted from [Settings - Hiding secret data using a JSON file](https://web.archive.org/web/20161008193637/http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/942/settings/8734/hiding-secret-data-using-a-json-file#t=201610081936376979593). The original authors were [Antoine Pinsard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529346/antoine-pinsard) and [fredley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319618/fredley). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/8734). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 942 and example ID: 8734.

**Hiding secret data using a JSON file**

When using a VCS such as Git or SVN, there are some secret data that must never be versioned (whether the repository is public or private).

Among those data, you find the `SECRET_KEY` setting and the database password.

A common practice to hide these settings from version control is to create a file `secrets.json` at the root of your project ([thanks "*Two Scoops of Django*" for the idea](https://github.com/twoscoops/two-scoops-of-django-1.8/blob/master/code/chapter_05_example_19.py)):

```
{
    "SECRET_KEY": "N4HE:AMk:.Ader5354DR453TH8SHTQr",
    "DB_PASSWORD": "v3ry53cr3t"
}
```

And add it to your ignore list (`.gitignore` for git):

```
*.py[co]
*.sw[po]
*~
/secrets.json
```

Then add the following function to your `settings` module:

```
import json
import os
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'secrets.json')) as secrets_file:
    secrets = json.load(secrets_file)

def get_secret(setting, secrets=secrets):
    """Get secret setting or fail with ImproperlyConfigured"""
    try:
        return secrets[setting]
    except KeyError:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Set the {} setting".format(setting))
```

Then fill the settings this way:

```
SECRET_KEY = get_secret('SECRET_KEY')
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgres',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': get_secret('DB_PASSWORD'),
    },
}
```

*Credits: [Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices for Django 1.8, by Daniel Roy Greenfeld and Audrey RoyGreenfeld. Copyright 2015 Two Scoops Press (ISBN 978-0981467344)](https://www.twoscoopspress.com/)*

---

> Excerpted from [Settings - Using Environment variables to manage Settings across servers](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006222759/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/942/settings/3580/using-environment-variables-to-manage-settings-across-servers#t=201710062227593129269). The original authors were [sudshekhar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819007/sudshekhar), [ssice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488191/ssice) and [NBajanca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4470542/nbajanca). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/3580). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 942 and example ID: 3580.

**Using Environment variables to manage Settings across servers**

Using environment variables is a widely used way to setting an app's config depending on it environment, as stated in [The Twelve-Factor App](http://12factor.net/config).

As configurations are likely to change between deployment environments, this is a very interesting way to modify the configuration without having to dig in the app's source code, as well as keeping secrets outside the application files and source code repository.

In Django, the main settings are located as `settings.py` in your project's folder. As it is a simple Python file, you can use Python's `os` module from the standard library to access the environment (and even have appropriate defaults).

### settings.py

```
import os

SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('APP_SECRET_KEY', 'unsafe-secret-key')

DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', "True") == "True"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split()

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('APP_DB_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME', 'db.sqlite'),    
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST', None),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', None),
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600,
    }
}
```

With Django you can change your database technology, so that you can use sqlite3 on your development machine (and that should be a sane default for committing to a source control system). Although this is possible it is not advisable:

> Backing services, such as the app’s database, queueing system, or cache, is one area where dev/prod parity is important. ([The Twelve-Factor App - Dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity))

Comment: what about Encrypted data?

Comment: @TheNone - What do you mean as encrypted data? Generally these two approaches are sufficient enough

Comment: @TheNone - By all means, if you have a more secure solution you are more comfortable using then by all means go for it. But I have never found a need for a more secure requirement than the env variables since our production is locked down to only the most trusted. I don't see a point in having the decryption in the same place as the encrypted file

Comment: @TheNone To be honest, that's the wrong approach to the problem. The settings that should be secret -- your secret key, database credentials, etc. -- should be local to your deployment, so the proper solution is to keep those settings out of source control altogether. The other settings can safely live in source control without any encryption. If an attacker has access to your deployment, and not just your source control, his approach won't add any security either, since the clear-text file is needed to actually deploy the application.

Comment: Please correct your DEBUG : 
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG','True') == 'True'

Comment: great answer. I wonder though, why it isnt baked into django. I dont like the "go figure this out yourself" approach. I'd have preferred a django that is production ready out of the box, without having to jump through so many hoops

Answer (score 0):

Would like to thank **Sayse** for the wonderful idea of using Environment variables. For those using Pycharm to connect to a mysql database, you need to create a 'USER' environment variable and call it using *os.environ.get('environment variable', '')* if you want to avoid storing the database password in the settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it isn't secure .

you mustn't upload those information to internet .

**what I always do is :**

- **Adding env file in the root directory .** 
  for example , if the project named MYPROJECT 
  the dir for env file would be MYPROJECT/env
- **Adding env file to .gitignore file.**
- **I use database url form , I found it more *elegant* , and less lines .**
  to use it type :

  - `pip install dj_database_url`
  - Add this line to settings.py

    `import dj_database_url`
  - Then as *simple and elegant* as this type :
    `DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/database_name'), }`
- Now , **replace the url with a keyword ,and hide the url safely in env file** , as :

  `DATABASES = { 'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')), }`

  note : this way you typed os.environ.get() only once.
- **Go to env file and add** :
  `export DATABASE_URL='postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/database_name'`
- **Don't forget** ! to let tell the terminal about those keywords! Type in terminal in project dir :
  `source env`

Good Luck .