# How to return false from string converted in bool

Tags: python, django

I can't return `False` in settings.py from docker(.env)

`DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG_MODE')
 DEBUG_MODE=False`

Python return:

```
x = False
bool(x)
False
print(bool(x))
False
x = 'False'
print(bool(x))
True
```

How to return False?

Comment: There is a difference between a boolean `False`, and a string `'False'`.

Comment: `eval(x)` maybe will work

Comment: What is that mode meant to demonstrate?

Comment: See [Django, Security and Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42077532/1324033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try:

`print(eval('False'))`

Take a look at its use in the documentation [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is not a good idea in general.

I would use the following:

```
b = False if x == 'False' else True
```

Answer (score 0):

Any non-empty string is truthy, so `bool('False')` returns True.

You can use a simple comparison:

```
print(x == 'True')
```

or you could use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse any Python literal.

```
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Comment: `print(x == 'True')` would make more sense than `print(x != 'True')`

Answer (score 0):

ANY string is binary encoded in ascii. so the code

```
x = ' ' ; print(bool(x))    | >>> True   |
```

as its not zero even if x=" " | where [ " " = whitespace ]

if you want to do as you said :

- METHOD 1 : [  **type(x) == str**  ]:

  - **return BOOLEAN True** if x= "anyString" & **False** if other type
- METHOD 2 : [ **isinstance ( x , str )** ]

  - **return BOOLEAN** **True** if true , wrap it with str(Your_test) to get string comparison
- METHOD 3 : **Complimentary Logic**

  - initially we give | x='False'
  - **boolean_value = x != 'False'**
  - print(boolean_value)   | >>> False
  - **double compliment** : **boolean_value = x == 'True'**
  - print(boolean_value)   | >>> False