# How do I allow my django website to be hosted by a local server (127.0.0.1) and a Heruko server

Tags: python, django, heroku, localhost

I don't know if I am explaining my problem correctly but I can clarify with the following picture of my settings.py file

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# DEBUG = True
DEBUG = False

# ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['sheryar-portfolio.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'pages',
    'calculator',
    'amino'
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Now here in ALLOWED_HOSTS, I have declared two hosts. 
The Heroku one is running perfectly whereas I am having some issues in the local one. 
It seems like that my static folder is not being located by django as I can only see the HTML of my website in local server.
In short, I cannot see the CSS being applied to my website when I am including the local server in ALLOWED_HOST

Comment: You should store it as an [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077532/django-security-and-settings/42077576#42077576) and then provide different values for local and live versions

Comment: Can you provide an example with code?